# Running Pub Upgrade in flutter installation taking too much time

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a serious issue trying to install flutter... The pub upgrade when you run flutter doctor have being running for the past one hour on my system... I have being stuck with this issue since yesterday i don't know what the exact problem is... I have tried installing via Android Studio and through command line... It ends up getting stuck at "Running Pub Upgrade"... [image]

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few things you can try,

Close Android studio,

Open Task Manager and see if any Dart/Flutter services are running, if yes then close them.

Clear `cache` from `flutter/bin` folder.

and now run again.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem. It was stuck on "Running pub upgrade..." for more than 24 hours.

On this GitHub thread someone solved it by turning Anti-virus shields off. [https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/61719][1] (Stuck at Running pub upgrade)

This solved the issue for me. I closed Windows PowerShell, and turned off Avast Anti-virus shields. I re-opened Windows PowerShell, ran flutter doctor and all went through perfectly with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I was a able to solve this problem, by downloading the flutter zip file in the flutter website, adding flutter/bin directory to my environment variables Path, restarting my system and running flutter doctor...

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem, but I solved it using another computer,
what I did was;

I cleared my cache folder in **flutter/bin** folder
then I copied the folder containing flutter SDK into another computer **C:** drive so the folder was like **C:\src\flutter** on the other computer(which was windows also), opened the folder, opened **flutter console**, and run `flutter doctor`. it worked fine on that computer, everything was in place, so I copied that same folder again back into my computer, replacing all exiting files and run `flutter doctor` on my computer and it worked for me.